# How to fix errors in passing an object from reactjs application to spring boot application using POST api?

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I want to sent an object from reactjs (frontend) to Spring boot application(backened) through POST api. For this I used fetch and json.stringfy.

```
myfunction(firstname, lastname, email, password, callback){
  const data = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    password: password
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:8080/data/somedata", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({data})
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Response ::", response.data);

    } else {
      callback(false, response.error);
    }
  });
  }
```

In the backend side I have Spring boot application exposing POST api,

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/somedata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addSome (@RequestBody Map<String,String> payload) {
    User n = new User();
    n.setFirstName(payload.get("firstname"));
    n.setLastName(payload.get("lastname"));
    n.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(payload.get("password")));
    n.setEmail(payload.get("email"));
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved User";
}
```

When I invoke api over POSTMAN, it works fine.
The issue is that json.stringify(data) is not giving expected result.

```
JSON stringified data :::  {"firstname":"testname","email":{"__reactInternalInstance$uzhpqmwh4k":{"tag":5,"key":null,"type":"input","stateNode":"~email","return":{"tag":5,"key":null,"type":"div","stateNode":{"__reactInternalInstance$uzhpqmwh4k":"~email~__reactInternalInstance$uzhpqmwh4k~return","__reactEventHandlers$uzhpqmwh4k":{"className":"col-75","children":{"type":"input","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"className":"form-input","type":"text","id":"email","value":""},"_owner":{"tag":2,"key":null,"stateNode":{"props":{"data":{"fullname":"testname","username":"","password":"test","email":"test@testmail.com"},......
```

I tried to use the below. Still, the json stringified data has unnecessary characters.
    JSON.stringify(data, getCircularReplacer())

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of my variables are of type object. I changed it to type string and the code works fine